# не добавляется поле в таблицу

Tags: sql

не могу добавить пустую строку,  выдает ошибку

```
USE [web_site_work_pez]
GO

SELECT [send_maill_infoID]
      ,[SM_Info_GroupID]
      ,[Order_str]
      ,[Info_str]
      ,[isStatic]
      ,[osrid]
  FROM [work].[send_maill_info] where [SM_Info_GroupID]=6
  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT send_maill_info ON;

INSERT  INTO work.send_maill_info (send_maill_infoID, SM_Info_GroupID, Order_str, Info_str, isStatic, osrid)
VALUES (344,6,70, ' ', 0,0);  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT send_maill_info ON;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так посмотрите, вы забыли указать схему

```
USE [web_site_work_pez]
GO

SELECT [send_maill_infoID]
      ,[SM_Info_GroupID]
      ,[Order_str]
      ,[Info_str]
      ,[isStatic]
      ,[osrid]
  FROM [work].[send_maill_info] where [SM_Info_GroupID]=6
  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [work].send_maill_info ON;

INSERT  INTO work.send_maill_info (send_maill_infoID, SM_Info_GroupID, Order_str, Info_str, isStatic, osrid)
VALUES (344,6,70, ' ', 0,0);  

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [work].send_maill_info ON;
```

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста как мне обновить строку там же только вместо одного слова, поставить другое. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если обновить то это Update со всеми вытккающими параметрами